# Logging in Java Web Start using log4j

Tags: java, log4j, java-web-start, web

I am migrating my application to Java Web Start.  I have a situation that my application logs the message using log4j and configuration file create the logs in the installation directory.

I am not sure how to create and store the logs while using Java Web Start. Could any one tell me how to specify the file location for log4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add following entry in the log4j.property file

```
log4j.appender.F.File=${user.home}/quest.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the option to the JVM when it starts.  On windows, this would look like:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:/MyApp/bin/log4j.properties
```

Comment: Hi dj.thanks for response but my problem is if I how to set the logs directory in log4j.properties, for example if I set (log4j.appender.F.File=logs/quest.log) then log4j is going to create the log file in (current dir/logs/quest.log) but since you can not read the memory area for jws so if we have to later on retrieved the logs for the debug purpose how we are going to do that, the question is how can we redirect the fileappender location to 'user.home' so that all logs get created at specific location and can be accessed later on. Hope I am clear this time.

Comment: Well thanks everyone I have found the solution we can use   following setting :                                                                log4j.appender.F.File=${user.home}/quest.log

Comment: @Ashish  Thanks for reporting back.  You should add that as an answer and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

While using log4j to log in your JWS application, your jnlp should contain reference to log4j library like this

```
<resources>
    <jar href="log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
</resources>
```

The log4j jar file should be in the same directory as of your JWS application jar file.

Where to Log : Most preferred location to log is inside user home as the user has all rights there to create and modify files. log4j.appender.F.File=${user.home}/test.log

You may also like to use log4j socket appender, which sends the logging output to remote server.